# Find point C if m(<ACB) is maximum

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A (0,9) B (0,4)  C $\epsilon$ OX  so C (x , 0)

What I did so far:
$\lVert AC\rVert$ = $\sqrt{x^2 + 81}$

AB = 5

Sin$\theta$ = $\frac{5}{\sqrt{x^2 + 81} }$

After setting the first derivative = 0

So Cot$\theta$ = $\frac{-x}{x^2 + 81}$

Now  I have 2 variables, any tips?

Comment: `Sin θ = ...` $\;\triangle ABC$ is not a right triangle, so $\sin \theta \ne AB / AC\,$.

Comment: that means x equals 2?

Comment: The way I'd find the angle is using the dot product: $\cos \theta = \frac{\langle \overrightarrow{CA}, \overrightarrow{CB} \rangle}{\lVert \overrightarrow{CA} \rVert \cdot \lVert \overrightarrow{CB} \rVert}$.  Then since $\cos$ is decreasing on $[0, \pi]$, $\theta$ is maximized exactly when $\cos \theta$ is minimized.

Comment: Ohhh... the clever solution would probably be: $\frac{c}{\sin C} = \frac{5}{\sin C} = 2R$ where $R$ is the radius of the circumscribed circle.  So, $C$ is maximized when $R$ is minimized, which happens exactly when the circle is tangent to the $x$-axis.  The center must be along the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ which is $y = \frac{13}{2}$.  So, the radius is $\frac{13}{2}$, and from there it should be simple geometry to find the $x$-coordinate of the center of the circle, which is the same as the $x$-coordinate of $C$ when angle $C$ is minimized.

Comment: its still hard when I use the dot product, can you go further

Comment: @cazanova Or you could use $2\, S_{ABC} = OC \cdot AB = CA \cdot CB \cdot \sin \theta\,$ to find $\sin \theta$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: all of these are brilliant solutions and I appreciate it, but I'm not that educated in math yet, can you solve it with simple vectors?

Comment: according to the cos$\theta\$ dot product rule, x became 6i

Comment: So, $\overrightarrow{CA} = (-x, 9)$ and $\overrightarrow{CB} = (-x, 4)$.  Then the dot product is what, and what are the norms of the vectors?

Comment: cos $\theta$ = ${x^2 + 36\over $\sqrt x^2 +81 \sqrt x^2 + 16$}$

Comment: OK, so using a computer algebra system I found $\frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{x^2+36}{\sqrt{(x^2+81)(x^2+16)}}\right) = \frac{25 x^3 - 900x}{(x^2+81)^{3/2} (x^2+16)^{3/2}}$.  (It hopefully shouldn't be impossible to do it by hand, I was just being lazy.)

Comment: I already fixed it, try refreshing.

Comment: so x is really equal to 6 but at first it was 6i

Comment: Well, $x=-6$ and $x=0$ also give local extrema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $O$ being the origin, write $\theta:=m\angle ACB$, $\alpha:= m\angle ACO$, and $\beta:=m\angle BCO$.  Try maximizing the *tangent* of $\theta$.

Since $\theta=\alpha-\beta$,  use the formula for the tangent of a difference to obtain
$$
\tan\theta = \tan(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{\tan\alpha -\tan\beta}{1+\tan\alpha\tan\beta}=\frac{\frac9x-\frac4x}{1+\frac9x\frac4x}
=\frac{5x}{x^2+36}.
$$
Use calculus to find that this last quantity is maximized at $x=6$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\text{Let}\;\;&A=(0,9)\\[4pt]
&B=(0,4)\\[4pt]
&C=(x,0)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

The goal is to find $x$ such that $\theta = \angle ACB$ is maximized.

Clearly $x=0$ is not a candidate.

By symmetry, we can assume, without loss of generality, that $x > 0$.

Using vectors,
$$
\cos(\theta)=\frac
{\vec{AC} \cdot \vec{BC}}
{{\Large{|}}\vec{AC}{\Large{|}}{\Large{|}}\vec{BC}{\Large{|}}}
=\frac{x^2+36}{\sqrt{x^2+81}\sqrt{x^2+16}}>0
$$
hence $\theta$ is acute.

Using Daniel Schepler's cool idea, the extended Law of Sines yields
$$\frac{5}{\sin(\theta)} = 2R$$
where $R$ is the circumradius of triangle $ABC$, hence 
\begin{align*}
&\text{$\theta$ is maximized}\\[4pt]
\iff&\text{$\sin(\theta)$ is maximized (since $\theta$ is acute)}\\[4pt]
\iff&\text{$R$ is minimized}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Let $Q$ denote the circumcenter of triangle $ABC$.

Since $Q$ is on the perpendicular bisector of segment $AB$, it follows that
$$Q = \left(q,{\small{\frac{13}{2}}}\right)$$
for some $q>0$.

By definition of $R$, we have
$$R^2 = |BQ|^2 = q^2 + \left({\small{\frac{13}{2}}} - 4\right)^2$$
hence minimizing $R$ is equivalent to minimizing $q$.

But we also have
$$R^2 = |CQ|^2 = (q-x)^2 + \left({\small{\frac{13}{2}}}\right)^2$$
hence
\begin{align*}
&|BQ|^2 = |CQ|^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&q^2 + \left({\small{\frac{13}{2}}} - 4\right)^2=(q-x)^2 
+\left({\small{\frac{13}{2}}}\right)^2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&q^2 + {\small{\frac{25}{4}}}=q^2-2qx+x^2+ {\small{\frac{169}{4}}}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&2qx=x^2+36\\[4pt]
\implies\;&q = \frac{x^2+36}{2x}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
But then, applying AM-GM,
$$q = \frac{x^2+36}{2x} = \frac{x}{2}+\frac{18}{x} \ge 2\sqrt{{\small{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(\frac{18}{x}\right)}}} = 6$$
with equality if and only if
\begin{align*}
{\small{\frac{x}{2}}}&={\small{\frac{18}{x}}}\\[4pt]
\iff x^2&=36\\[4pt]
\iff\;\,x&=6\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Update: I see now that I missed the second part of Daniel Schepler's idea.

We have $R^2 = |BQ|^2 = q^2 + \frac{25}{4}$, so on the domain $(0,\infty)$, $R$ is strictly increasing as a function of $q$, and has range $(\frac{5}{2},\infty)$.

Since $Q$ is on the line $y = \frac{13}{2}$ and $C$ is on the $x$-axis, $R = |CQ| \implies R \ge \frac{13}{2}$.

It follows that $R$ is minimized when $R = \frac{13}{2}$, which happens when the circumcircle just touches the $x$-axis.

Thus, setting $R = \frac{13}{2}$,
\begin{align*}
&R^2=|BQ|^2
\qquad\qquad
\\[4pt]
\implies\; &{\small{\frac{169}{4}}}=q^2 + {\small{\frac{25}{4}}}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &q^2 = 36\\[4pt] 
\implies\; &q = 6\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and then
\begin{align*}
&R^2=|CQ|^2\\[4pt]
\implies\; &{\small{\frac{169}{4}}}=(6-x)^2 + {\small{\frac{169}{4}}}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &x = 6\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Done!